# The timer not let the user to edit

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, timer

I'm a begginer and i build a timer app and i want the app to allow the user to edit the time. like in the android build in timer. and i wrote the code and it not really works it's show like it can be edit but when i'm trying to write something, it's change for a sec and go back to what it's been before..

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_stopwatch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.adir.stopwatch.StopwatchActivity"
    android:background="#000000"

    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickReset"
        android:text="@string/reset"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/stop_button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="92sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

android:inputType="time"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickStart"
android:text="@string/start"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickStop"
        android:text="@string/stop"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/start_button"></Button>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
public class StopwatchActivity extends Activity {
    private int seconds=0;
    private boolean running;
private boolean wasRunning;
public String time;
    public int hours=seconds/3600;
    public int minutes=(seconds%3600)/60;
    public int secs=seconds%60;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stopwatch);
        if(savedInstanceState!=null){
            seconds=savedInstanceState.getInt("seconds");
            running=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");
            wasRunning=savedInstanceState.getBoolean("wasRunning");
        }
        runTimer();
    }

    public void onClickStart(View view) {

        running = true;
    }
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        wasRunning=running;
        running=false;
    }

    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        if(wasRunning){
            running=true;
        }
    }

    public void onClickStop(View view) {
        running = false;


    }

    public void onClickReset(View view) {
        running = false;
        seconds = 0;
    }

    private void runTimer() {

        final EditText timeView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        time=timeView.getText().toString();
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d",hours, minutes, secs);

                timeView.setText(time);
                if (running) {
                    seconds--;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });


    }
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    savedInstanceState.putInt("seconds",seconds);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("running",running);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("wasRunning",wasRunning);
}

    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        wasRunning=running;
        running=false;
    }

    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(wasRunning){
            running=true;
        }
    }


}
```

What do i need to fix?

Comment: Do you want the timer to be a Countdown Timer?

Comment: @espa_network yes. so the user will write like 45 sec and it will countdown

Comment: You should use `CountDownTimer` instead of `Timer` Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will give you a good idea of what to do. When you click the button, it will get the text of the EditText and put it into string. Then it will convert into int. Then you can put the new int variable `time` into your  `CountDownTimer` function's 1st parameter to set the length of the timer.

```
   Button submit;
   TextView timerText;
   EditText editTextTime;
   CountdownTimer yourTimer;
   String  timeString;
   int time;

  submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

     timeString = String.valueOf(editTextTime.getText());
     time = Integer.valueOf(timeString);


        }
    });


    yourTimer = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


        int seconds = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds %= 60;
        minutes %= 60;


        if (seconds < 10 && seconds >= 1) {
            timerText.setText("" + seconds);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }
}.start();
```

Comment: You added one more button for edit? it's not possible to just press on the timer and it will let me edit?